# RevenueCat - Ionic React - CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "PurchasesHybridCommon":

Tags: ionic-framework, capacitor, revenuecat

I'm currently trying to implement the RevenueCat SDK with Ionic React (Capacitor) and whilst building the app using Ionic Appflow I get the following error

```
[18:38:13]: ▸ [error] Error running update: Analyzing dependencies
[18:38:13]: ▸ Fetching podspec for `Capacitor` from `../../node_modules/@capacitor/ios`
[18:38:13]: ▸ Fetching podspec for `CapacitorCommunityHttp` from `../../node_modules/@capacitor-community/http`
[18:38:13]: ▸ Fetching podspec for `CapacitorCordova` from `../../node_modules/@capacitor/ios`
[18:38:13]: ▸ Fetching podspec for `CordovaPlugins` from `../capacitor-cordova-ios-plugins`
[18:38:13]: ▸ Fetching podspec for `CordovaPluginsStatic` from `../capacitor-cordova-ios-plugins`
[18:38:13]: ▸ [!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "PurchasesHybridCommon":
[18:38:13]: ▸ In Podfile:
[18:38:13]: ▸ CordovaPluginsStatic (from `../capacitor-cordova-ios-plugins`) was resolved to 2.4.0, which depends on
[18:38:13]: ▸ PurchasesHybridCommon (= 1.2.0)
[18:38:13]: ▸ None of your spec sources contain a spec satisfying the dependency: `PurchasesHybridCommon (= 1.2.0)`.
[18:38:13]: ▸ You have either:
[18:38:13]: ▸ * out-of-date source repos which you can update with `pod repo update` or with `pod install --repo-update`.
[18:38:13]: ▸ * mistyped the name or version.
[18:38:13]: ▸ * not added the source repo that hosts the Podspec to your Podfile.
[18:38:13]: ▸ Note: as of CocoaPods 1.0, `pod repo update` does not happen on `pod install` by default.
[18:38:13]: ▸ Sync finished in 3.219s
```

Comment: Have you tried running `pod install --repo-update`?

Comment: Cheers, thought I wouldn't be able to run that due to being on Windows. But I managed to get around it by adding it to "scripts" "build" in package.json.. which made Ionic Appflow run it for me. Problem sorted:)

Answer (score 13):

The comment from @enc_life worked for me (on a Flutter app, not React, but I guess the iOS part works the same either way):

```
pod install --repo-update
```

After that everything worked like a charm.

The error message I had was

```
[!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "PurchasesHybridCommon":
    In Podfile:
        purchases_flutter (from `.symlinks/plugins/purchases_flutter/ios`) was
        resolved to 1.4.3, which depends on PurchasesHybridCommon (= 1.4.5)

None of your spec sources contain a spec satisfying the dependency: 
   `PurchasesHybridCommon (= 1.4.5)`.
```

Comment: This did not work for me. :(

Comment: Maybe helpful for others: I needed to run a 'pod update' first. Afterwards the 'pod install' worked perfectly.

Comment: It worked for me in Flutter, since I ran `pod update` first. @joshlat94 if it worked for you, would it be useful for others if you mark this answer as valid.